# apache shark installation on spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

When running shark on spark cluster with one node
I'm getting the following error.  can anyone please solve it...
Thanks in advance

```
error::
Executor updated: app-20140619165031-0000/0 is now FAILED (class java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/trendwise/Hadoop_tools/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java" (in directory "/home/trendwise/Hadoop_tools/spark/spark-0.9.1-bin-hadoop1/work/app-20140619165031-0000/0"): error=2, No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience "No such file or directory" is often a symptom of some other exception.  Usually a "no space left on device" and sometimes "too many files open".  Mine the logs for other stack traces and monitor your disk usage and inode usage to confirm.